# SAS HDD won't reinstall, keeps flickering and shows red light

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an HP ProLiant SE316M1R2 server. I had 3 hard disks in the Smart Array P410i (they're Fujitsu, two RAID 0 in bay 1 and one RAID 0 in bay 2), so I uninstalled one of them because I was testing something.

Now, I can't reinstall it. It keeps flickering + shows red light. The ORCA utility and the ACU don't recognize it.

Does this mean it should be replaced? It was just working a couple of days ago. How can I test it?

Comment: Can you clarify your setup? 3 disks in 2 bays constituting 2 raids?

Comment: @KonradGajewski Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So which one did you pull out?

Comment: @KonradGajewski the lonely one.

Comment: Well, the disk should at least be recognized and show up in ORCA, even if the whole setup went down the drain. There might be something wrong with your disk/backplane/controller.